# Set webpacker dev server watch options (poll, aggregate_timeout) via environmental variables on Lando

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpacker, lando

The project is using Ruby [Webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) and [Lando](https://lando.dev/) is used for local development. 
My `config/webpacker.yml` contains this:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  dev_server:
    public: some.lndo.site
    host: '0.0.0.0'
    port: 3035
    ...
    watch_options:
      poll: 1000
      aggregate_timeout: 500
```

So, insetad of adding/editing parameters in `webpacker.yml` for my local environment I can set some of these options as environmental variables in my `.lando.yml` file (i.e. `public`, `host`, `port`):

```
services:
  appserver:
    type: ruby:2.6.3
    overrides:
      environment:
        WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_PUBLIC: some.lndo.site
        WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST: '0.0.0.0'
        WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_PORT: '3035'
        ...
```

This works.

**Question:** But how can I set the environmental variables for `watch-options` (i.e. `poll`) via environmental variable?

I've tried these, but with no luck:

```
WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_WATCHOPTIONS_POLL 
WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_WATCH_OPTIONS_POLL
WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_POLL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like nested JSON within the `dev_server` object is currently not supported (as of Webpacker v4.2.0), where the `key` interpolated in the `ENV["WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_#{key.upcase}"]` would only match a top-level key: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/417542c8ed7d344ecc24b3ae40e303d478ad50d0/lib/webpacker/dev_server.rb#L59-L61

```rb
# env_prefix = "WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER".freeze
def fetch(key)
  ENV["#{env_prefix}_#{key.upcase}"] || config.dev_server.fetch(key, defaults[key])
end
```

Since I'm guessing you don't need the Rails server to know about the watch poll options, it shouldn't be necessary to pass the dynamic values to `config/webpacker.yml`. I would instead read them in `config/webpack/development.js`, i.e., straight into Webpack:

```js
// config/webpack/development.js

const environment = require('./environment.js');

environment.config.merge({
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      poll: process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_WATCH_POLL,
      aggregateTimeout: process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_WATCH_TIMEOUT
    }
  }
});

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: Looks like a workaround that works. Thanks!

The only fix needed: `watch_options` should be replaced by `watchOptions`, otherwise it throws an error "webpack Dev Server Invalid Options: options should NOT have additional properties". The same for `aggregateTimeout` etc.

Comment: Edited your answer and made fixes described above, please approve

Comment: Thanks, approved!